# How do you solve the equation $e^{-x}(1+x) = m$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Applying $\log$ to both sides gives $-x + \log(1+x) = \log (m)$, which doesn't seem much easier to solve. I thought about expanding $\log(1+x)$ in a Taylor series but if $m$ is such that $x$ is large it's not a good approximation.

I also tried integrating both sides but I get $2 - 2e^{-x} - xe^{-x} = mx$ which I'm not sure what to do with.

What am I missing here? This looks like it should be very simple.

Comment: It's not particularly simple. You'll need the [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) function to solve it exactly.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you. What kind of math course could I expect to learn about this function? Complex analysis?

Comment: You might learn about it in complex analysis. It depends on the priorities of the person teaching it. It's not a particularly fundamentally useful function in complex analysis, so I'd expect you'd probably learn about it from a course that needs to use this function. For example, an advanced DE course might mention Delay Differential Equations, and use the Lambert W function to solve a simple one. I personally learned about it as a tiny aside when I was studying convex functions (though I can't actually remember why the function was relevant; it could just have been an example).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just so the question is answered, we can, as stated above, use the Lambert W function. We first divide both sides by $-e$:
$$e^{-x - 1}(-x - 1) = -\frac{m}{e}.$$
Taking the Lambert W function of both sides:
$$-x - 1 = W\left(-\frac{m}{e}\right) \implies x = -W\left(-\frac{m}{e}\right) - 1.$$
It's worth pointing out that the Lambert $W$ function is defined only on $[-e^{-1}, \infty)$ and multivalued on $[-e^{-1}, 0)$. So, in order for there to be a solution, we require $m \le 1$, and in order for the solution to be unique, we require $m \le 0$.

EDIT: Actually, $W$ is also single-valued at the point $-e^{-1}$, so indeed the solution is unique at $m = 1$ too.